# Reference Request for Solid Angles

Tags: reference-request, solid-angle

I'm looking for a reference that has a discussion of **solid angles**. Many facts about them are available in various places online, but I haven't had any luck finding a text that treats them. I might be barking up the wrong tree, but neither Do Carmo's *Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces* nor any of the volumes of Spivak's *A Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry* (save a brief problem in volume I) covers them. Neither does, for example, Marsden and Tromba's *Vector Calculus*. Perhaps texts on mathematical physics would be worth consulting.

I would be grateful for any pointers!

Answer (score 1):

You might look up references for spherical trigonometry.  Here are a couple of books:

[M'Clelland and Preston (1912)](https://ia600308.us.archive.org/7/items/treatiseonspheri033264mbp/treatiseonspheri033264mbp.pdf), "A treatise on spherical trigonometry with applications to spherical geometry and numerous examples", Macmillan

[Todhunter (1886)](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/19770/19770-pdf.pdf), "Spherical trigonometry for the use of colleges and schools", Macmillan

Comment: Also -- [google books search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22solid+angle%22&tbm=bks) (search [restricted to before 1926](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22solid+angle%22&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1700%2Ccd_max%3A1925&tbm=bks), thus likely to be freely available) *AND* [search for results at archive.org](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22solid+angle%22+archive.org) (many freely available and most others viewable) *AND* [google scholar search](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22solid+angle%22).